# AsynchronousFileChannel write operation, blocks sometimes?

Tags: java

I recently started using Java AsynchronousFileChannel for a project of mine, where i want to write to files as quick as possible. When i came to test my project, i realised that maybe read and write operations where not really asynchronous for me! I made a very simple test program to see if write and read methods are blocking or not, by writing bytes to 2 files, one for each of my disks.

```
ByteBuffer bufferc=ByteBuffer.allocate(75000000);//~75MB
ByteBuffer bufferd=ByteBuffer.allocate(75000000);
for (int i=0; i<75000000; i++)
{   bufferc.put((byte)1);   bufferd.put((byte)1); }

bufferc.flip(); bufferd.flip();

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
AsynchronousFileChannel channelc =AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Paths.get("C:\\ppp"), getReadWriteOptions(),executor, new FileAttribute<?>[0]);
AsynchronousFileChannel channeld =AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Paths.get("D:\\ppp"), getReadWriteOptions(), executor, new FileAttribute<?>[0]);

long  start = System.currentTimeMillis();   
System.out.println("start");
Future futurec=channelc.write(bufferc, 0);
System.out.println(futurec.isDone());
Future futured=channeld.write(bufferd, 0);
System.out.println(futured.isDone());
long elapsedTimec = System.currentTimeMillis()- start; 

channelc.close();
channeld.close();
System.out.println("time="+elapsedTimec);
```

So, im writing two buffers, into two different files. Because each buffer is about 75 MB, i suppose that each buffer cannot be written immediatly to my disk, so i would expect as my output something  like

```
false false time=
```

which would mean for me that the write operations are "given" to the executorService, and the program continues to run. In multiple runs of this program, this does happen for me, but NOT always. I mean, i get output like

```
start true true time=2621
```

or

```
start false true time=3039
```

or if im lucky

```
start false false time=235
```

The times really differ, and i dont even understand why i do get the first two outputs! I'd like someone to explain me factors that affect this output, and/or how i am going to get only the 3rd of the above outputs!

Comment: I get timings like `start false false time=3` even `time=1` as you are not waiting for the write to complete, I don't see why it would be taking any time at all to *start* the write. BTW: You can use direct ByteBuffers and you don't have to populate the buffer to send it (it will just be full of zeros)

Comment: Which Java 7 are you using? I am using Java HotSpot 7 update 3.

Comment: i tried the allocated buffer, without populating them, and i got like true, true, time=1, but in my case no byte was written (tried futurec.get()), and for me its because i didnt populate them!

Comment: to be honest i 've never heard java hotspot :S, i just know i have JavaSE-1.7.. but i dont think you mean this!

Comment: If you don't populate them, you shouldn't flip() them as well.

Comment: There are lots of versions of Java. Oracle has JRocket and HotSpot (The later is the old Sun version) Java SE is a platform which covers every complicate JVM.

Comment: you are right about the flip! but still i get the same outputs.. so you mean SE should be ok, or maybe there could be a problem with that??

Comment: The latest version should be fine. It also shouldn't block as you suspect. I don't know why it would block for you.

Comment: BTW: Does it have to work this way or are you looking for any solution which is very fast.  I have a solution which is around 100 nano-second and doesn't create any garbage (or use back ground threads)

Comment: It needs to perform asynchronous operations, so i suppose it has to work somehow like this! of course anything that could help  me or learn me something is totally accepted!

Comment: Does it need to be asynchronous, or does it need to be low latency?  If it could be faster, would that be better even if it were synchronous?

Comment: Anyway in answer to you other question here is a library I wrote which works for me. https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Chronicle

Comment: The concept was that being asynchronous-would make it really fast! So i should do something with asynchronous.. Thank you so much for the library! It seems very interesting in the description, and maybe it can help me too!!

Comment: The point is only the time it takes to write the data to memory matters. The library help speed up the serializatio/logging of data as well.  There is no creating an object(s) which is passed to a background thread etc.  Also if the program crashes, no data is lost because its the OS' job to write the data to disk in the background. (Of course if the OS crashes ...)